# CRM 2016 Working Hours Calendar Currently in use

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2016

[image]

In microsoft crm 2016 update 1, I am trying to create business hours for an SLA that is restricted to the working hours of nine to five. I can create a customer service schedule and apply that to the SLA but I get the below error.

I have only this schedule in that area, no holiday schedules, I am wondering if I am missing some other schedule related to the individual user? I also create another schedule as it says that one is in use but I get the same error?

As soon as the SLA is applied I get this error when entering the SLA applied entity.

[image]

I'm not going to enter the actual details as it shows too much organisation relevant information.